# Error when trying to load data from Ignite into Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ignite

I have a two-node spark cluster. On both the master/slave node I am running ./bin/ignite.sh and both nodes are able to discover each other.

Spark version: 2.4.3

Ignite version: 2.7.6

Now, my spark-defaults.conf looks like this

```
spark.jars.packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3,org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark:2.7.6
spark.driver.memory 8G
spark.executor.memory 4G
spark.driver.maxResultsSize 4G
```

I am starting pyspark as follows:

```
pyspark --jars $IGNITE_HOME/libs/*.jar,$IGNITE_HOME/libs/optional/ignite-spark/*jar,$IGNITE_HOME/libs/ignite-spring/*jar,$IGNITE_HOME/libs/ignite-indexing/*jar
```

and

```
>>> df = spark.read.format('mongo').option('uri' , 'mongodb://ec2-X-XXX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/cit.table_a').load()
19/10/21 20:07:30 WARN MongoInferSchema: Field 'authors' contains conflicting types converting to StringType
19/10/21 20:07:30 WARN MongoInferSchema: Field 'venue' contains conflicting types converting to StringType
>>> df.count()
2616
>>> import os
>>> configFile = os.environ['IGNITE_HOME'] + "/config/default-config.xml"
>>> df.write.format("ignite").option("table", "test1").option("primaryKeyFields", "_id").option("config", configFile).save()
19/10/21 20:08:22 WARN G: Ignite work directory is not provided, automatically resolved to: /home/ubuntu/apache-ignite/work
19/10/21 20:08:23 WARN IgniteKernal: Please set system property '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to avoid possible problems in mixed environments.
19/10/21 20:08:23 WARN GridDiagnostic: Initial heap size is 126MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
19/10/21 20:08:23 WARN TcpCommunicationSpi: Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
19/10/21 20:08:23 WARN NoopCheckpointSpi: Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
19/10/21 20:08:23 WARN GridCollisionManager: Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
19/10/21 20:08:24 WARN PartitionsEvictManager: Logging at INFO level without checking if INFO level is enabled: Evict partition permits=2
19/10/21 20:08:24 WARN TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder: TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder has no pre-configured addresses (it is recommended in production to specify at least one address in TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder.getAddresses() configuration property)
19/10/21 20:08:26 WARN IgniteKernal: Nodes started on local machine require more than 80% of physical RAM what can lead to significant slowdown due to swapping (please decrease JVM heap size, data region size or checkpoint buffer size) [required=10749MB, available=7975MB]
>>> igdf = spark.read.format("ignite").option("config", configFile).option("table", "test1").load()
>>> igdf.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 523, in count
    return int(self._jdf.count())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o56.count.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference.withQualifier(Lscala/Option;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/AttributeReference;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.ignite.IgniteOptimization$$anonfun$pushDownOperators$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(IgniteOptimization.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.ignite.IgniteOptimization$$anonfun$pushDownOperators$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(IgniteOptimization.scala:86)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.ignite.IgniteOptimization$$anonfun$pushDownOperators$1.applyOrElse(IgniteOptimization.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.ignite.IgniteOptimization$$anonfun$pushDownOperators$1.applyOrElse(IgniteOptimization.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.ignite.IgniteOptimization$.pushDownOperators(IgniteOptimization.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.ignite.IgniteOptimization$.apply(IgniteOptimization.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.ignite.IgniteOptimization$.apply(IgniteOptimization.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2835)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can someone please help what I am doing wrong here? I have tried a couple of things but no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a bunch of internal changes, Spark 2.4.x is not currently supported. It should work with 2.3.x though.

Support for later versions is in the works, hopefully ready for Ignite 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Spark 2.4 is not supported yet.

Here is the ticket on Apache Ignite JIRA, you could track the status here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12054